# WebView2 Source property doesn't initiate CoreWebView2

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

I've spent half an hour trying to figure out this tedious issue where you're unable to Navigate strings unless the Source property is set.

After all, I figured out a workaround hack since WebView2 demands an absolute path to an html file or nothing else.

```cs
Markdown.Focus(); 
Markdown.BringIntoView();

Markdown.Source = new Uri(Path.GetFullPath("null.html"), UriKind.Absolute);
Markdown.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

Markdown.NavigateToString(htContent);
```

Even after all of this. It still says "You need to set the Source property!!". This is driving me nuts.

`null.html` is a valid html file too. It's just empty since the HTML I need to display is way too dynamic to buffer into a file.

Comment: I think, you should skip the first 2 lines or move them under the the line where you set the source. What line do you get the error?

Comment: @PoulBak Hey, I know you just posted an answer, but anyways it's on the last line with NavigateToString.

Comment: I think, it doesn't like an empty document (an empty document is not `html`). But my answer should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the code, you have, try this:

```
await Markdown.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
Markdown.NavigateToString(htContent);
```

Now you don't have to set the `Source` property.

BTW: You don't have to set the other properties either, the `WebView2` Control is automatically displayed.

Comment: Is WPF able to call async methods? The function I need this in responds to KeyDown events. I'll be able to test it in ~15m.

Comment: Mark the eventhandler method with `async`.

Comment: Well yeah. Didn't think that WPF would know how to identify & call a coro, guess I'm about to find out anyways. I;ll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Good news, it went through. Just gotta resolve a missing WebView2Loader.dll now.

Comment: In Project Properties, Build, choose either 'x86' or 'x64', not 'anycpu'.